# Access VBA Converting An Array to Individual Records

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-access, listbox, multi-select

I'm working on a database with 2 main tables and a linked table which contains the foreign keys from the 2 tables. I created a form in Access and the intent of the form is to use a drop-down to select 1 option from one table and use a multi-select list box to allow users to select multiple options from the other table. The user would then click a button and my code (see below) should create a record in the linked table for each selected option in the list box. For example:

User creates a new record on the form, selects "Quality Assurance" from the drop-down list, and chooses 2 options from the list box. When the user clicks the button "cmdAddCompToCurr", 2 records should be created in the linked table.

When I test the button it's not quite right. The code doesn't convert the array created from the list box selections into individual ID numbers. No matter what items I choose from the listbox, I always get the same ID number in the linked table.

Code:

Private Sub Command0_Click()

```
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Variant

 Set db = CurrentDb()
 Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_CurCom_Link", dbOpenDynaset)

If List89.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No components were selected"
    GoTo Endme

End If

If List89.ItemsSelected.Count >= 1 Then
    i = List89.ListCount
    fld_ComponentID = List89.Column(0, 0)
    fld_ComponentCode = List89.Column(1, 0)
    fld_ComponentTitle = List89.Column(2, 0)
    fld_CompRevision = List89.Column(3, 0)

End If

For Each i In List89.ItemsSelected
    rs.AddNew
    rs!fld_CurriculumID = fld_CurriculumID
    rs!fld_ComponentID = fld_ComponentID
    rs.Update
```

Next
Endme:
 End Sub

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental issue is you have assigned your `fld_ComponentID` variable before (and outside of) your `for` loop. This means it gets set only once, before the loop, and every iteration of the loop will use that same value. Also because it is hard-coded to `.Column(0, 0)`, it gets set to whatever is in the *first row* regardless of what the user actually *selects*.

Instead, move the `fld_ComponentID` definition to inside the `for` loop, and also have it dynamically reference `.Column(0, i)`, i.e.:

```
    fld_ComponentID = List89.Column(0, i)
    rs!fld_ComponentID = fld_ComponentID
```

However you will notice the variable itself becomes redundant, so you can just:

```
    rs!fld_ComponentID = List89.Column(0, i)
```

And note the preceding `IF...END IF` block is actually redundant, so can be removed entirely.

You have not defined `fld_CurriculumID` anywhere. Be wary that without `Option Explicit` this will automatically generate a variable with default value, which will *not* throw an error and is *seldom* what anyone intends. For the full answer below I've assumed the relevant control is named `txtCurriculumID`.

After a few control flow changes as well, an alternative to your sub can be:

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim i As Variant

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("tbl_CurCom_Link", dbOpenDynaset)

    If List89.ItemsSelected.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No components were selected"
    Else
        For Each i In List89.ItemsSelected
            rs.AddNew
            rs!fld_CurriculumID = txtCurriculumID.Value
            rs!fld_ComponentID = List89.Column(0, i)
            rs.Update
        Next i
    End If
```